# Define Terrain/Elevation textfile data format

Tags: raster, elevation, terrain, file-formats

I have a program that can visualize terrain/elevation data but will only recognize files in the below format. It has the extension `.map` but it is not recognized by QGIS or GDAL so I believe it may be another form of data.

When opened in a text file, it appears like this:

```
Example Map
XScale: 8.455
YScale: 10.447
XOrigin: 606319.184
YOrigin: 4056521.23
NumberOfCols: 91
NumberOfRows: 73
RangeUpper: 68.81
RangeLower: 30
0057.70 0058.18 0058.73 0059.29 0059.78 0060.18 0060.51 0060.81 0061.14 0061.46 0061.71 0061.81 0061.73 0061.52 0061.26 0061.07 0060.98 0060.98 0061.03 "...
```

The strings of data go on and on. Can anyone identify this format?

Would like to be able to convert to this from other elevation data types: GeoTIFF, DEM.

Comment: What's the name of the program?  Are you comfortable using Python if a driver doesn't exist?

Comment: @mikewatt It is a program made long ago as a student project, so it doesn't have any recognizable name. I am comfortable with python, what would you recommend?

Comment: It is similar to [Esri ASCII grid format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid#ASCII), which is [supported by GDAL](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/aaigrid.html). But I think (not sure) that it can handle just square pixels.

Comment: Definitely look into the various ASCII drivers as @GabrielDeLuca suggests, maybe one of them is compatible as-is and you can simply leverage gdal_translate.  Otherwise I suggest using `rasterio` rather than the GDAL bindings. 1) Parse the header into a dict, 2) use that shape info to initialize an empty numpy array, 3) read the file line-by-line and insert the values into the array, 4) create a transform using the header info + `rasterio.transform.from_origin()`, 4) use rasterio to open a file and write out the array.  If you get stuck post up your code and we can take a look.